# FastAPI application won't start when importing routers

Tags: python, authentication, import, fastapi

I'm trying to import some authentication related routers to my main class in a FastAPI project, but if I add this import, the application starts without giving any results:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

from api.v1.users import routers

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

app.include_router(routers.get_users_router())

This is what api.v1.users.routers looks like:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

from auth import auth_backend, fastapi_users

users_router = APIRouter()


def get_users_router():
    users_router.include_router(fastapi_users.get_auth_router(auth_backend), prefix="/auth/jwt", tags=["auth"])
    users_router.include_router(fastapi_users.get_register_router(), prefix="auth", tags=["auth"])
    users_router.include_router(fastapi_users.get_reset_password_router(), prefix="auth", tags=["auth"])
    users_router.include_router(fastapi_users.get_verify_router(), prefix="auth", tags=["auth"])
    users_router.include_router(fastapi_users.get_users_router(), prefix="users", tags=["users"])
```

I don't see any error. If I run the application it just won't load.

What am I doing wrong?? I would appreciate any help thanks!

Comment: `get_users_router` does not return a router (it doesn't return anything) - you're just creating a router and adding routes to it, but you never add it to anything. I'm not sure what the goal of having `get_users_router` is; you could just drop the function and import `users_router` from `api.v1.users.router` directly instead.

Answer (score 0):

This would seem more likely to work

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

from auth import auth_backend, fastapi_users

def get_users_router():
    users_router = APIRouter()
    users_router.include_router(fastapi_users.get_auth_router(auth_backend), prefix="/auth/jwt", tags=["auth"])
    users_router.include_router(fastapi_users.get_register_router(), prefix="auth", tags=["auth"])
    users_router.include_router(fastapi_users.get_reset_password_router(), prefix="auth", tags=["auth"])
    users_router.include_router(fastapi_users.get_verify_router(), prefix="auth", tags=["auth"])
    users_router.include_router(fastapi_users.get_users_router(), prefix="users", tags=["users"])
    return users_router
```